# custom d3 linear scale that returns null for null values instead of 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3.scale.linear() scale that outputs values for my line chart when it is fed data. My data set contains values between 0 and 100, as well as `null` values. The chart must show gaps in the data, so in addition to returning integer values for any integer input, I need my scale to return `null` if I input `null`. A regular d3.scale.linear() will return `0` if `null` is passed in.

My initial solution was to do the following:

```
    var customScale = function(val){
        if (val === null) return null;
        else return d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100])(val);    
    }
```

so that `customScale(50)` returns `0.5` and `customScale(null)` returns `null`.

However, doing it this way means I lose other functions of d3.scale.linear() like `.invert()`

Is there a way to somehow extend d3.scale.linear() so that it can include my custom conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For null values my function returns null (d3.scale.liner() returns 0 in this case). The primary approach is to wrap the original scale and all its methods.

I didn't test this function for all cases. But for basic functionality it's working. Unfortunately I didn't found  easier way to do it :(

```
/**
 * d3.scale.linear() retrun 0 for null value
 * I need to get null in this case
 * This is a wrapper for d3.scale.linear()
 */
_getLinearScaleWithNull: function() {
    var alternativeScale = function(origLineScale) {
        var origScale = origLineScale ? origLineScale : d3.scale.linear();

        function scale(x) {
            if (x === null) return null; //this is the implementation of new behaviour
            return origScale(x);
        }

        scale.domain = function(x) {
            if (!arguments.length) return origScale.domain();
            origScale.domain(x);
            return scale;
        }

        scale.range = function(x) {
            if (!arguments.length) return origScale.range();
            origScale.range(x);
            return scale;
        }

        scale.copy = function() {
            return alternativeScale(origScale.copy());
        }

        scale.invert = function(x) {
            return origScale.invert(x);
        }

        scale.nice = function(m) {
            origScale = origScale.nice(m);
            return scale;
        }

        scale.ticks = function(m) {
            return origScale.ticks(m);
        };


        scale.tickFormat = function(m, Format) {
            return origScale.tickFormat(m, Format);
        }

        return scale;
    }

    return alternativeScale();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The D3 way of doing this would be to handle this not in the scale, but in the shape generating function that you pass the scale to. D3 provides the function [`.defined()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined) for this purpose. For example if you're drawing a line:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .defined(function(d) { return d.x !== null; });
```

The problem with defining a custom scale that omits such values is that then other things like the axes would break. Similarly, you won't lose any of the other functionality a scale provides with this method.